# Why does Flow infer type in an unexpected way?

Tags: javascript, enums, flowtype, string-literals

I have this sort of code:

```
export type MapType = "AdventureMap" | "GuidebookMap";

type MapContext = {|
  mapType: MapType
|}

const context: MapContext = { mapType: "GuidebookMap" };

const { mapType } = context;

// A: no error in this line
if (mapType === "ABC-INVALID") {}

function fun(value: MapType) {
  // B: error in this line
  if (value === "123-INVALID") {}
}

// C: error in this line
fun(mapType);
```

When compiling this in Flow, line B and C fails, because it infers that type of `mapType` is `MapType | string`. Why does it do that? Is there a way to change it?

I expect it to fail on lines A and B, as it does on Typescript.

---

I can do this:

`const mapType: MapType = context.mapType;`

but it somewhat beats the purpose as I'm forced to specify types explicitly. Also, you can not "extract" multiple properties in one statement and I have to specify types for each. Is there a setting in the config to make it work more like Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this
when you are destructuring, you can specify types like that.
/* @flow */

```
export type MapType = "AdventureMap" | "GuidebookMap";

type MapContext = {|
  mapType: MapType
|}

const context: MapContext = { mapType: "GuidebookMap" };

const { mapType }:{
    mapType: MapType
} = context;

// A: no error in this line
if (mapType === "ABC-INVALID") {}

function fun(value: MapType) {
  // B: error in this line
  if (value === "123-INVALID") {}
}

// C: error in this line
fun(mapType);
```

Comment: Yeah, this works, but doesn't really answer the question of why does Flow do that. Or is there a setting to make it behave like Typescript in this regard.